# How to Insert Data into Redis

Tags: redis

I am quite new to Redis before posting this question i tried couple of option in Redis such as HASH, SET, MULTI SET to create table like below but i could not make it

I need the below table to be inserted into Redis and insertedtime column should be with Latest timestamp as first row for every Processnumber

```
Processnumber       | insertedtime
------------------+--------------------------
370905502434097 | 2017-05-11 07:11:10+0000
370905502434097 | 2017-05-11 07:09:09+0000
370905502434097 | 2017-05-11 07:06:55+0000
370905502434097 | 2017-05-11 07:03:55+0000
4024007195422711 | 2017-05-11 07:11:10+0000
4024007195422711 | 2017-05-11 07:09:09+0000
4024007195422711 | 2017-05-11 07:06:55+0000
4024007195422711 | 2017-05-11 07:03:55+0000
5591980872085425 | 2017-05-11 07:11:10+0000
5591980872085425 | 2017-05-11 07:09:09+0000
5591980872085425 | 2017-05-11 07:06:55+0000
5591980872085425 | 2017-05-11 07:03:55+0000
5591980872085425 | 2017-05-11 06:46:35+0000
```

Any Help or Suggestion is Highly Appreciated

**Thanks in Advance!!!...**

Answer (score 0):

With Redis you first need to know what type of queries you'll be running on the data in order to know how to "insert" it.

Looking at your table, it appears like the process number is a unique identifier and the two main questions that are askable are:

1. Given a processnumber, give me back a timestamp
2. Given a datestamp range, give me back the processnumbers in it

For this type of operations, a Sorted Set would do nicely. Read more about the [`ZADD`](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) and its friends.